# Image at the top of the tableview

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

Hey I am making an app that has to show a big image at the top of the grouped tableview, I don't want the image to be in tablecell because it looks stupid that way. I just want the image to float there, but I have no idea how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the table view's `tableHeaderView` property, like this:

```
UIImageView *topImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my logo.png"];
topImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
topImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theTableView.bounds.size.width, 100); // replace 100 with the height of your image, plus a bit if you want it to have a margin
topImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

theTableView.tableHeaderView = topImage;
[topImage release];
```